# Modify array json api response laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I'm fearly new to laravel, please assist me with resolving this issue. I need to edit my response on the image attribute to return as a URL instead of just the image name stored on the database on the array response.

Here is my source code:

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function serv_list(){
   $services = Add_Service::all();

   return $services;
 }
```

current response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "service_name": "Hair",
        "desc": "Everything that has to do with hair and more",
        "image": "1590713947.jpg",
        "created_at": "2020-05-29T00:59:08.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-05-29T02:14:45.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "service_name": "Nails",
        "desc": "Nails Services",
        "image": "1590722173.jpg",
        "created_at": "2020-05-29T03:16:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-05-29T03:21:09.000000Z"
    }
]
```

How I need the response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "service_name": "Hair",
        "desc": "Everything that has to do with hair and more",
        "image": "https://google.com/avatars/1590713947.jpg",
        "created_at": "2020-05-29T00:59:08.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-05-29T02:14:45.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "service_name": "Nails",
        "desc": "Nails Services",
        "image": "https://google.com/avatars/1590722173.jpg",
        "created_at": "2020-05-29T03:16:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-05-29T03:21:09.000000Z"
    }
]
```

I tried the following way:

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function serv_list(){
   $services = Add_Service::all();

   foreach($services as $service){
      $id  = $service->id;
      $name = $service->service_name;
      $desc = $service->desc;
      $pic = $service->image;
   }
   $image = 'https://google.com/avatars/'.$pic;
   $data = array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name, 'desc'=>$desc, 'image'=>$image);
   return $data;
 }
```

The response is:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Nails",
    "desc": "Nails Services",
    "image": "https://google.com/avatars/1590722173.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use basic [Laravel Transform](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-transform) for this.

```
$services->transform(function($q){
    $q->image = 'https://google.com/avatars/' . $q->image;
    return $q;
});
```